# Using many mutex locks

Tags: c, linux, pthreads, hpc

I have a large tree structure on which several threads are working at the same time. Ideally, I would like to have an individual mutex lock for each cell.

I looked at the definition of `pthread_mutex_t` in `bits/pthreadtypes.h` and it is fairly short, so the memory usage should not be an issue in my case.

However, is there any performance penalty when using many (let's say a few thousand) different `pthread_mutex_t`s for only 8 threads?

Comment: A few thousand on a single tree is .. kind of questionable .. but hard to say without actually seeing it. Can you post enough code to show a reasonably comprehensive example of what you are doing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are locking and unlocking very frequently, there can be a penalty, since obtaining and releasing locks does take some time, and can take a fair amount of time if the locks are contended.

When using many locks in a structure like this, you will have to be very specific about what each lock actually locks, and make sure you are careful of AB-BA deadlocks.  For example, if you are changing the tree's structure during a locking operation, you will need to lock all the nodes that will be changed, in a consistent order, and make sure that threads working on descendants do not become confused.

If you have a very large number of locks, spread out across memory, caching issues could cause performance problems, depending on the architecture, as locking operations will generally invalidate at least some part of the cache.

Your best bet is probably to implement a simple locking structure, then profile it, then refine it to improve performance, if necessary.  I'm not sure what you're doing with the tree, but a good place to start might be a single reader-writer lock for the whole tree, if you expect to read much more than you update.

**"We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil."**
-- Donald Knuth

Answer (score 1):

Your locking/access patterns need to be stated in order to properly evaluate this.  If each thread would only hold one or a few locks at a time and the probability that any two or more threads would want the same lock at the same time is low (either a random access patter or 8 runners on different positions on a circular track running at roughly the same speed or other more complicated things) then you will mostly avoid the worst case where a thread has to sleep to get a lock (or in some cases have to get the OS involved to decide who wins) because you have so few threads and so many locks.

If each thread might want hundreds or thousands of locks at any one time then things will start to change.

I won't touch deadlock avoidance because I don't know anything about the container that you are using, but you need to be aware of the need to avoid them.